# In MongoDB, strategy for maximizing performance of writes to daily log documents

Tags: mongodb, io, nosql

We have a collection of log data, where each document in the collection is identified by a MAC address and a calendar day. Basically:

```
{
  _id: <generated>,
  mac: <string>,
  day: <date>,
  data: [ "value1", "value2" ]
}
```

Every five minutes, we append a new log entry to the data array within the current day's document. The document rolls over at midnight UTC when we create a new document for each MAC.

We've noticed that IO, as measured by bytes written, increases all day long, and then drops back down at midnight UTC. This shouldn't happen because the rate of log messages is constant. We believe that the unexpected behavior is due to Mongo moving documents, as opposed to updating their log arrays in place. For what it's worth, `stats()` shows that the paddingFactor is 1.0299999997858227.

Several questions:

1. Is there a way to confirm whether Mongo is updating in place or moving? We see some moves in the slow query log, but this seems like anecdotal evidence. I know I can `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`, then `db.system.profile.find()`, and finally look for `"moved:true"`, but I'm not sure whether it's ok to do this on a busy production system.
2. The size of each document is very predictable and regular. Assuming that mongo is doing a lot of moves, what's the best way to figure out why isn't Mongo able to presize more accurately? Or to make Mongo presize more accurately? Assuming that the above description of the problem is right, tweaking the padding factor does not seem like it would do the trick.
3. It should be easy enough for me to presize the document and remove any guesswork from Mongo. (I know the [padding factor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor) docs say that I shouldn't have to do this, but I just need to put this issue behind me.) What's the best way to presize a document? It seems simple to write a document with a garbage byte array field, and then immediately remove that field from the document, but are there any gotchas that I should be aware of? For example, I can imagine having to wait on the server for the write operation (i.e. do a safe write) before removing the garbage field.
4. I was concerned about preallocating all of a day's documents at around the same time because it seems like this would saturate the disk at that time. Is this a valid concern? Should I try to spread out the preallocation costs over the previous day?

Comment: Scott Hernandez answered this question on the Google Group, so I'm posting a list to his answer: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8a24e7f3faf95f71#

Comment: Latest update: we're still trying to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following combination seems to cause write performance to fall off a cliff:

1. Journaling is on.
2. Writes append entries to an array that makes up the bulk of a larger document

Presumably I/O becomes saturated. Changing either of these factors seems to prevent this from happening:

1. Turn journaling off. Use more replicas instead.
2. Use smaller documents. Note that document size here is measured in bytes, not in the length of any arrays in the documents.
3. Journal on a separate filesystem.

In addition, here are some other tricks that improve write throughput. With the exception of sharding, we found the improvements to be incremental, whereas we were trying to solve a "this doesn't work at all" kind of problem, but I'm including them here in case you're looking for incremental improvements. The 10Gen folks [did some testing and got similar results](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8a24e7f3faf95f71/7b26f9b8cd057e69#7b26f9b8cd057e69):

1. Shard.
2. Break up long arrays into several arrays, so that your overall structure looks more like a nested tree. If you use hour of the day as the key, then the daily log document becomes:
    `{"0":[...], "1":[...],...,"23":[...]}`.
3. Try manual preallocation. (This didn't help us. Mongo's padding seems to work as advertised. My original question was misguided.)
4. Try different --syncdelay values. (This didn't help us.)
5. Try without safe writes. (We were already doing this for the log data, and it's not possible in many situations. Also, this seems like a bit of a cheat.)

You'll notice that I've copied some of the suggestions from 10Gen here, just for completeness. Hopefully I did so accurately! If they publish a cookbook example, then I'll post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb will try to presize documents adaptively as it learns how you are updating documents over a period of time. More information can be found at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor

If you find that mongodb is still moving documents after a while, you may want to try out manually padding the document, so that you wont have to worry about it having to move documents.

In your case it seems like you should be able to do so, given the fact that the number of samples in a day is constant (for your 5 min interval.) Can you print the output from db.{yourcollectionname}.stats() ?

Regarding point # 4: You can spread out the costs as u mentioned, but i would try out inserting the documents when you need them the first time to see how it performs and then try other things out.

you maybe able to bypass this particular problem by exploring other schemas, but am not sure what all you have tried out. Are you storing key value pairs within the array, with the timestamp being the key? 
an example modification would be to move to something like: 
{
    id: 1,
    metrics: 
        { 
          "00:05" : { "metric1" : "value1"},
          "00:10" : { "metric2" : "value2" }
        }
}

Comment: I'm aware of adaptive presizing, but if it was working then I don't think we'd see the IO pattern that I described. I'll add the stats to the question. Yes, I'd like to manually pad the document; see my question 3. Can you provide details about exactly how to do so? Yes, we are trying things out, but as I said I expect problems so  an answer from somebody with experience would be more helpful. I don't think the schema is the core of this problem, since each write just adds the value to the end of an array field, but I've added an example to the question just in case.

Comment: what is the padding factor that mongodb has computed for your collection?

Comment: it's in the question: 1.0299999997858227

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a predictable/ constant number of pushes in your data array.
(24*60) / 5 = 288 in one day.
I would strongly suggest preallocating 288 elements array ( or 1000 for flexibility and expansion in case you decide to do it every 3 minutes for example) in the document, and then updating the document accordingly for each data entry addition.
This is how to proceed :

-Add 1 more key to each document, this will maintain the key number to update in in the associative `data` array. eg. Initially the document will look like on first insert or refresh of
data array by update:

```
{
      _id: <generated>,
      mac: <string>,
      day: <date>,
      data: { "1" : "myGarbageValue","2" : "myGarbageValue",
              "3" : "myGarbageValue"....."1000": "myGarbageValue" }
      n: 1
}
```

For each update,you have to do a upsert on `data` key equal to `n`, and increment `n`
After 2 updates of data :

```
 {
          _id: <generated>,
          mac: <string>,
          day: <date>,
          data: { "1" : "myFirstValue","2" : "mySecondValue",
                  "3" : "myGarbageValue"....."1000": "myGarbageValue" }
          n: 3
    }
```

## Pros :

- Less growth of document, would be best if your `myGarbageValue`,`myFirstValue`,`mySecondValue` are consisent in size and format.
- `n` always tells you current size of your `data` array, and lets you run range queries to find `data` array size, which was not possible in your previous stucture as $size operator can only return exact size match, not ranges .
  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size
- Upsert performance is better when the document does not expand. Here it is a clean key based upsert eg on `data.23` , whereas in old structure it was a `$push` which has linear insertion performance and gets slower as your `data` array grows.

## Cons :

- More disk space is used by your data, that should not be a problem as you refresh your data every 24 hours.

Hope these suggestions help. Try it, and let all of us know if it benefits you.

Comment: Do you know the official source of the "push has linear insertion performance" information? I know of this test http://blog.axant.it/archives/236, but it only claims "probably." We'll try the associative array suggestion, but I'd be surprised if this works. We're well under the 5000 threshold that's mentioned. Also, I can't think of an explanation for why an linear insertion algorithm would translate to the physical IO behavior that we see, since it can't possibly be moving every entry.

Comment: Hi, jtoberon, Not officially documented, but it was observed during some benchmarking. However for an array of small size of 288 like yours,that won't make much of difference.
And you are right, the IO difference is not made by insertion/updating algorithm difference, it is made by the fact that due to preallocation of elements in  associative array, your document object does not grow.Hence there are less movements done by mongodb, less IO.

Comment: The associative array change did not help. The IO load smooths out, but at a level that's worse than the peaks of what we see when we use a normal array and `$push`.